# Reconstruction of training path from saved checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm training a simple fully convolutional network with batchnorm. I saved a checkpoint after the initialization. Then, I restored it and ran the training again (with the same hyperparameters). However, I got different results from the two training procedures. All my seeds (python, numpy, and tf) were set equal on the beginning of the two runs.

What could possibly be the reason for the mismatch?

Comment: Can you confirm that you made your seeds identical _after_ the initialization, not before? The initialization process will use random numbers. If you don't reset the seeds after that happens, they will be in a different state than the snapshot which did not pull those random numbers.

Comment: @mcskinner On both training procedures I set the seeds at the file header. On the first module, I initialize and save the weights. On the second module, I restore the weights from the first module. Do you mean I should set the seeds after performing the initialization?

Comment: Yes. Set the seeds after performing initialization. The initialization can use any seed you want, but then you have to fix it after that to get the same starting seed for the restored checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Setting seeds in the file header will lead to different outcomes, since initialization will consume some of the random values before you get to training.

So you should set the seeds after performing initialization. The initialization can use any seed you want, including another fixed seed, but then you have to reset it again for training.

Here is some very high level pseudo-code, which assumes you have functions to to build, initialize, and train the model. And also functions to save and load the checkpoints.

```py
def set_seeds(seed):
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)

# Make a checkpoint.
set_seeds(INIT_SEED)
model = build_model()
model = initialize_model(model)
save_checkpoint(model)

# Or load a checkpoint.
model = load_checkpoint()

# At this point seeds need to be identical.
# So re-fix the seeds for training, then proceed.
set_seeds(TRAIN_SEED)
trained = train_model(model)
```